How to run Django test names verbosely without displaying too much logging
I would like to run the tests in my Django project, displaying the test names, but without displaying the logging output of the database migrations.
If I do not pass the -v 2 flag, then I don't get to see the test names, which I want to see:
$ python manage.py run test
Found 1 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.053s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

However, if I pass the flag -v 2 to increase the verbosity level, then I see both the test names and the logging information from the database migrations:
$ python manage.py test -v 2
Found 1 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_projectname')...
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: allauth, django_browser_reload, django_extensions, forms, google, hijack, hijack_admin, messages, runserver_nostatic, simple_deploy, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  # ... cut for brevity
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
test_hello (projectname.test_login.LoginTest.test_hello) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.046s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_projectname')...

How do I display just the test names, without displaying all this additional logging information?

Well, on Linux/Mac, you can use v 2 verbosity and then grep the output like that: manage.py test -v 2 | grep test_. Something similar probably exists on Windows

@user19315471 That would filter out things like test failures, so it's not ideal.

from unittest import TextTestResult, TestResult

from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class CustomTestResult(TextTestResult):
    """Custom test result class that prints test names without colors or times."""

    def startTest(self, test):
        super().startTest(test)

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        """Print the test name for successful tests."""
        print(f"{test}")
        TestResult.addSuccess(self, test)

    def addError(self, test, err):
        """Print the test name for tests that errored."""
        print(f"ERROR - {test}")
        TestResult.addError(self, test, err)

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        """Print the test name for tests that failed."""
        print(f"FAIL - {test}")
        TestResult.addFailure(self, test, err)


class GlobalTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    """Global unit-tests runner."""

    def __init__(self, exclude_apps=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize variables for testing."""
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_resultclass(self):
        """Return customized class for results."""
        return CustomTestResult

then add TEST_RUNNER = 'common.tests.GlobalTestRunner' in test_settings.py
NOTE: This also adds elapsed time on each test so remove it if you want.
Output
test_advisory_meeting_create_view_invalid_requests (apps.advisory.tests.advisory_meeting_list_test.AdvisoryMeetingListTest)
test_advisory_meeting_list_with_team_meeting (apps.advisory.tests.advisory_meeting_list_test.AdvisoryMeetingListTest)
test_advisory_meeting_retrieve_team_meeting (apps.advisory.tests.advisory_meeting_retrieve_test.AdvisoryMeetingRetrieveTest)
test_team_meetings_list_with_correct_data (apps.advisory.tests.committee_team_meetings_test.CommiteeTeamMeetingsTest)
test_team_meetings_list_with_team_composition (apps.advisory.tests.committee_team_meetings_test.CommiteeTeamMeetingsTest)
test_committee_meeting_delete_with_correct_data (apps.advisory.tests.committee_meeting_update_test.CommitteeMeetingUpdateTest)
test_committee_meeting_delete_with_invalid_meeting (apps.advisory.tests.committee_meeting_update_test.CommitteeMeetingUpdateTest)
test_upcoming_meetings_list_with_correct_data (apps.advisory.tests.unprocessed_meeting_list_test.UnprocessedMeetingsListTest)
test_upcoming_meetings_list_without_added_subteams (apps.advisory.tests.unprocessed_meeting_list_test.UnprocessedMeetingsListTest)
test_advisory_approval_email_with_team_meeting (apps.advisory.tests.misc.advisory_meeting_approval_email_test.AdvisoryApprovalEmailTest)
test_advisory_reminder_email_without_leads (apps.advisory.tests.misc.advisory_reminder_email_test.AdvisoryReminderEmailTest)
test_advisory_review_email_with_team_meeting (apps.advisory.tests.misc.advisory_review_email_test.AdvisoryReviewEmailTest)
test_advisory_schedule_email_with_follow_up (apps.advisory.tests.misc.advisory_schedule_email_test.AdvisoryScheduleEmailTest)
test_advisory_schedule_email_with_team_meeting (apps.advisory.tests.misc.advisory_schedule_email_test.AdvisoryScheduleEmailTest)
test_advisory_schedule_email_with_team_meeting (apps.advisory.tests.misc.advisory_team_email_test.AdvisoryTeamEmailTest)
test_advisory_approval_email_overlapping_attendees (apps.advisory.tests.misc.update_meeting_calendar_task_test.UpdateMeetingCalendarTest)


You could've removed that unecessary code. i have updated it as you required.

Thanks! The edited answer is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!
